# WebSphere 7. Inject EJB from another application

Tags: java, websphere, ejb-3.0

I am trying to inject an EJB with the @EJB annotation:

- when I inject an EJB into another EJB in the same ear it works fine.
- when I inject an EJB into another EJB from another ear in the same
  server I get an exception:

> EJB threw an unexpected (non-declared) exception during invocation of
>   method "sayHello".  Exception data: javax.ejb.EJBException: Injection
>   failure; nested exception is:
>   com.ibm.ejs.container.EJBNotFoundException:  EJB with interface
>   com.mycompany.myapp.ejb.test2 not present in application myapp1

I'm using WebSphere 7 and EJB 3.0. When I'm doing a jndi lookup myself, it works fine. How do I let the container know from where to inject my remote beans?

myapp1.ear contains the following : myapp1.jar (where the EJB is)

myapp1 EJB :

```
package com.mycompany.myapp1.ejb.test1;

@Remote
public interface HelloEjb1 { 
    public String sayHello();
}
```

EJB Impl :

```
package com.mycompany.myapp.ejb.test1;

@Stateless
public class HelloEjbImpl1 implements HelloEjb1 {

    @EJB
 HelloEjb2 helloEjb2;

    @Override
    public String sayHello() {
        return HelloEjb2.sayHello();
    }
}
```

myapp2.ear contains the following : myapp2.jar (where the EJB is)

myapp2 EJB :

```
package com.mycompany.myapp2.ejb.test2;

@Remote
public interface HelloEjb2 { 
    public String sayHello();
}
```

EJB Impl :

```
package com.mycompany.myapp2.ejb.test2;

@Stateless
public class HelloEjbImpl2 implements HelloEjb2 {

    @Override
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specify the binding when deploying the application ([1](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/urun_rapp_instw_gendefbind.html), [2](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/crun_app_bindings.html)), or include a [META-INF/ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/cejb_bindingsejbfp.html) in your client (myapp1) EJB module.  It would look something like this:

```
<ejb-jar-bnd
    xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-ejb-jar-bnd_1_0.xsd"
    version "1.0">
  <session name="HelloEjbImpl1">
    <ejb-ref name="com.mycompany.myapp.ejb.test1/helloEjb2"
        binding-name="myapp2/myapp2.jar/HelloEjbImpl2#com.mycompany.myapp1.ejb.test1.HelloEjb1"
  </session>  
</ejb-jar-bnd>
```

The `ejb-ref name="..."` can be simplified if you use `@EJB(name="myrefname")`.  The binding-name can be simplified if your myapp2.jar includes a similar binding file with an `<interface class="..." binding-name="..."/>` element.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about first approach (binding when deploying the application)?  Thanks.

Comment: I've updated to add a few InfoCenter links. There's plenty of information in the InfoCenter, but if you want detailed answers, it might be easier to start a new question.